# Get-Content with authentication

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a file from a network share. I need to pass credentials to authenticate.

```
 #Define credentials
#===========
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString “mypassword” -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“myuser”, $secpasswd)


#Get the file
#===========
$commandresult = Get-Content "\\$tsmhost\prtg_output\STGPOOLS.txt" -Credential $credentials -Force
```

However, this results in

> Get-Content : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. The 
>   FileSystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive cmdlet. 
>   Perform the operation again without specifying credentials.

Of course, if I don't specify the credential, I get an access denied. 

I believe there is a workaround by mounting the shared folder as a network drive, but this seems inefficient and, since the script might run multiple times at once, I might have duplicate drives.


Any what would be the most efficient way to accomplish this?


Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a PSDrive with `New-PSDrive` using your Credentials, then use the `Get-Content` to read the file:

```
New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\$tsmhost\prtg_output -Credential $credentials
```

Then:

```
Get-Content X:\STGPOOLS.txt
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, this is a workaround, but isn't this very inefficient? Also, since the script might run multiple times at once, I might have duplicate drives.

Comment: also you can use native `net use` then it will not ask you again for the same resource, once you entered valid creds